# What am I iterating in this find_if function?

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
bool isNotValid (char a) {
    if (isalpha(a) || a == '_')
    {
        cout << "\n- isalpha";
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\n- notalpha";
        return 1;
    }
}

bool test123(const string& test)
{
    return find_if(test.begin(), test.end(), isNotValid) != test.end();
}

int main()
{
    string test;
    cout << "Test input: ";
    cin >> test;
    
    if (!test123(test))
        cout << "\n- Valid\n";
    else
        cout << "\n- Not Valid\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This is part of my code to check the validity of username in my program. I don't really understand what exactly I am iterating through when I insert the string into my function as address of the string. CPP reference states that find_if iterates from first to last position of a sequence.

Poked through the code with cout at different location, still didn't quite catch what is going on.

Comment: You are iterating through the string, calling isNotValid() for each character.  find_if  will return the position of the first invalid character it finds (isNotValid()  == true) or test.end() if all calls  to isNotValid() returned false.

Comment: If it helps you understand, a string is a sequence of characters (basically `std::string` is almost identical to `std::vector<char>` though there are some key differences)

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation, I will look up std:string and std::vector<char> later.

Comment: You can use `std::find_if` here, but imho the function that should be used is [`std::all_of`, `std::any_of` or `std::none_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of). (In this case the equivalent to `find_if(test.begin(), test.end(), isNotValid) != test.end()` is `std::any_of(test.begin(), test.end(), isNotValid)`)

Comment: Note to someone that might be reading this in the future: The std::find_if is returning an iterator, you might find some unexpected behavior as my code returned it into a bool. You may use the iterator like a pointer.

Comment: @fabian Great suggestion. I changed my answer a bit to incorporate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating your string. You did not pass the address of the string. The function takes the string as a reference to `const`, meaning it passes the actual string (no copy is made) and the function is not allowed to modify the string. You are iterating character by character in your string and calling your function `isNotValid()` on each character.

Notes:

- Instead of returning 1 or 0 from `isNotValid()`, return `true` or `false`.
- Consider flipping your logic and renaming the function to `isValid()` instead. You would also have to change `test123()` to use `std::find_if_not()`. Finally, you would check if the returned iterator **is** `end()` and not if it's not.
- **But**, if you do change `isNotValid()` to `isValid()`, you'd be better off switching from `std::find_if()` entirely to to `std::all_of()`. It makes more sense, is more readable, and returns a `bool` directly (No need to compare against end()).
- **But** if you want to keep your function `isNotValid()`, the comment that suggests using `std::any_of()` is what I would recommend for the same reasons.

Here's my take on your code:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool isValid(char a) {
  return std::isalpha(static_cast<unsigned char>(a)) || a == '_';  // !
}

bool test123(const std::string& test) {
  return std::all_of(test.begin(), test.end(), isValid);  // !
}

int main() {
  std::string testOne{"i_am_valid"};
  std::string testTwo{"i_am_invalid_123"};

  std::cout << "Testing: " << testOne << " : " << std::boolalpha
            << test123(testOne) << '\n';
  std::cout << "Testing: " << testTwo << " : " << std::boolalpha
            << test123(testTwo) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
❯ ./a.out 
Testing: i_am_valid : true
Testing: i_am_invalid_123 : false
```

I would argue that readability has stayed largely the same, but the mental load has been shifted; the Boolean flips make a bit more sense.

As you progress in your learning, you might not even want to have the function `isValid()` if it's a one-off thing. C++11 introduced lambdas, or functions as objects. C++20 also introduced ranges, so you don't have to pass a pair of iterators if you intend to iterate the whole container anyway.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool test123(const std::string& test) {
  return std::ranges::all_of(test, [](const auto& c) {
           return std::isalpha(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)) || c == '_';
         });  // !
}

int main() {
  std::string testOne{"i_am_valid"};
  std::string testTwo{"i_am_invalid_123"};

  std::cout << "Testing: " << testOne << " : " << std::boolalpha
            << test123(testOne) << '\n';
  std::cout << "Testing: " << testTwo << " : " << std::boolalpha
            << test123(testTwo) << '\n';
}
```

That's a bit hairy to read if you're not familiar with lambdas, but I find lambdas useful for checks like this where you're just doing it the one time.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250904/discussion-on-answer-by-sweenish-what-am-i-iterating-in-this-find-if-function).